# iframe or object load function not working

Tags: php, jquery, pdf

I want to show loading icon until pdf is loaded into the webpage.I have pasted what I have tried but loading icon keeps on displaying even the pdf is loaded fully. So, I concluded `$iFrame.load(function()` doesn't trigger anything. Got this code from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/selvadevel/BXe8C/375/). But in JSFiddle it is working.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<style>
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid green;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
    var $iFrame = $('iframe'); 
    $iFrame.load(function(){
        $('h3').html('PDF Loaded!');
    });

    $('h3').html('Loading PDF...');
    $iFrame.attr('src', 'http://listic.ru/jQuery_Cookbook.pdf');


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3></h3>
<iframe></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What your actual problem? Your jsFiddle working fine.

Comment: ya, but `$iFrame.load(function()` doesn't trigger anything when I try

Comment: I dont know what your problem but In your given jsfiddle it working fine

Comment: I have posted my answer but because of some cache problems it doesn't seem to work sometimes. How to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to do an additional check for caches files (who fired the event, just before added an event handler listening for it). I tried the following jquery and it worked fine.

```
 $iFrame.on('load', function() {
  $('h3').html('PDF loaded...');
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```